# How to draw vertical line between mulitple grid columns using css

Tags: css, css-grid

I am working on a web page that shows some statistics about an app. I want to use CSS grid to layout the statistics in four columns, with an image on the left and three text items on the right. I also want to add vertical lines between the columns to separate them visually. I have written some HTML and CSS code for this, but I am not getting the result I want. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

Html code:

```
<div class="stats__number">
          <img
            src="img/d4d-3d.png"
            alt="3D logo of D4D Offers app in middleeast"
            class="stats__number_img"
          />
          <img
            src="img/download.svg"
            alt=""
            class="stats__number_svg download_svg vertical_line"
          />
          <span class="stats__number_text download_text vertical_line">
            <span class="stats__number_text_main color_primary">6 M+</span
            >Downloads</span
          >
          <img
            src="img/star.svg"
            alt=""
            class="stats__number_svg star_svg vertical_line"
          />
          <span class="stats__number_text star_text vertical_line">
            <span class="stats__number_text_main">4.5</span>Star Rating
          </span>
          <img
            src="img/review.svg"
            alt=""
            class="stats__number_svg review_svg vertical_line"
          />
          <span class="stats__number_text review_text vertical_line">
            <span class="stats__number_text_main">87 K+</span>Reviews
          </span>
        </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
 .stats { 
     grid-column: full-start/full-end; 
     padding: 10% 15%; 
     position: relative; 
    }
    .stats__img {
      position: absolute;
      left: -13%;
      top: 16%;
      width: 26%;
     }
    
    .stats__number {
      display: grid;
      place-items: center center;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 10rem);
     }
    .stats__number_img {
      position: relative;
      top: -10%;
      height: 25rem;
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
      grid-row: 1 / 3;
      justify-self: end;
     }
    .stats__number_svg {
      height: 7rem;
      width: 7rem;
    }
    .stats__number_svg.star_svg {
      width: 16rem;
      height: 16rem;
      filter: none;
    }
    .stats__number_svg.review_svg {
      width: 9rem;
      height: 9rem;
      filter: none;
    }
    .stats__number_text {
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     font-weight: 700;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 1.6;
    }
    .stats__number_text_main {
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 2.4rem;
      display: block;
    }
    .stats__number_text.download_text {
      grid-column: 2/3;
      grid-row: 2/3;
    }
    .stats__number_text.star_text {
      grid-column:3/4; 
      grid-row:2/3; 
    }
    .stats__number_text.review_text { 
      grid-column:4/5; 
      grid-row:2/3; 
    }
```

This is what i am trying to achieve using this code. Any help is appreciated.
[what I am looking to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhAcb.png)
This is what i have achieved using the above code [what I achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxb4e.png)

Comment: Please also add your HTML to the question so as to make a [mre].

Comment: @InSync I have added as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a semantically correct markup HR and style it with CSS ([working demo](https://codepen.io/OldPadawan/pen/jOexQPO)):

```
<div class="stats">
  <div class="stats__number">
      <img
        src="img/d4d-3d.png"
        alt="3D logo of D4D Offers app in middleeast"
        class="stats__number_img"
      />
<hr class="vertical spliter-1"/>
      <img
        src="img/download.svg"
        alt=""
        class="stats__number_svg download_svg vertical_line"
      />
      <span class="stats__number_text download_text vertical_line">
        <span class="stats__number_text_main color_primary">6 M+</span
        >Downloads</span
      >
<hr class="vertical spliter-2"/>
      <img
        src="img/star.svg"
        alt=""
        class="stats__number_svg star_svg vertical_line"
      />
      <span class="stats__number_text star_text vertical_line">
        <span class="stats__number_text_main">4.5</span>Star Rating
      </span>
<hr class="vertical spliter-3"/>
      <img
        src="img/review.svg"
        alt=""
        class="stats__number_svg review_svg vertical_line"
      />
      <span class="stats__number_text review_text vertical_line">
        <span class="stats__number_text_main">87 K+</span>Reviews
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add the following to your CSS and adjust to your needs. You can add some shadow to it, fade out and more:

```
hr.vertical {
  height: 50%;
  width: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.spliter-1 {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 38%;
}
.spliter-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
.spliter-3 {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 70%;
}
```

Comment: I would argue that using `hr`is the opposite of semantic. From the MDN docs, The hr HTML element represents a thematic break between paragraph-level elements: for example, a change of scene in a story, or a shift of topic within a section.

Comment: Thanks, for the response. I was looking for a more direct approach without using absolute positioning. I think making an absolute positioning element responsive is a headache in itself.

Comment: you also have the option of a div around img+text and you shadow the right border, that would add some little code but would make it easier for responsiveness.

Comment: Would [this kind of trick](https://codepen.io/OldPadawan/pen/bGmMPmd) be a good start to play around? I've modified some of your CSS base to make it more clear for me, we'd need to adjust to new parameters to align them again though.